# Как найти все возможные записи слова `banana` в строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

Например: в строке `bbananana` все возможные записи будут выглядеть так:

```bash
1.  b-anana--
2.  b-anan--a
3.  b-ana--na
4.  b-an--ana
5.  b-a--nana
6.  b---anana
7.  -banana--
8.  -banan--a
9.  -bana--na
10. -ban--ana
11. -ba--nana
12. -b--anana
```

Я примерно понмаю как решить эту задачу простыми методами (циклами, условиями и т.д.), но меня интересует другой вопрос: **Как решить эту задачу при помощи регулярного выражения?**

Comment: [С сомнением] по-моему, регулярные выражения не для этого...

Comment: Регулярки выдают непересекающиеся совпадения. А вы ищите много совпадений на одном и том же участке. Не получится. Можно сделать регулярку, которая выдаст все возможные положения первой буквы. Или второй. Или какой-то конкретной. Но не более.

Comment: А как решить эту задачу простыми методами? никак не могу сообразить

Comment: Есть такая штука в регулярных выражениях, как **positive lookahead**, которая смотрит назад. Так что @stanislav-volodarskiy не прав, можно работать и с пересечениями. Сама в этой фиче не очень разбираюсь, но может поможет. Хотя мне кажется машинное обучение тут поможет куда больше чем регулярка

Comment: @Archery,  думаю у вас не получится выдать несколько совпадений, начинающихся в одном месте. Даже с lookahead хотя бы на один символ надо сдвигаться. Я имел это в виду, когда писал что можно найти все возможные положения первой буквы.

Comment: `\b-*b(?:-*a-*n){2}-*a=*\b` посмотрите тут:  https://regex101.com/r/epLRdI/1 хорошей редактор для регулярных выражений

Comment: @ipatev_nn, из строки ```bbananana``` должно получится 12 матчей, а вы ответы в регулярку поставили

Comment: @NEStenerus nester, тут даже трудно представить в каком виде вы предполагаете получать ответ от регулярного выражения. ```replace``` все то что не подходит на тире? Да, все равно трудно представить

Answer (score 0):

Если перед и после каждой буквы слова может быть от 0 до бесконечности дефисов, то регулярка получится такая:

```
-*b-*a-*n-*a-*n-*a-*
```

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли вопрос.  Есть строка ```bbananana``` и из нее надо получить 12 совпадений перечисленных в вопросе

Comment: использование регулярок для этих целей не годится