# Максимальное количество совпадений регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Увидел вопрос про [поиск всевозможных бананов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423560) и задумался вот о чём. Можно подобрать строку из 10 символов и регулярное выражение которое вернёт 11 совпадений. Например в Питоне:

```
@>>> len(re.findall(r'\b|$', "0 2 4 6 8 "))
11
```

Можно ли больше? Можно получить двеннадцать совпадений из десятисимвольной строки? И вообще, как соотносятся длина строки и максимальное возможное число совпадений регулярного выражения?

Вопрос не ограничивается Питоном. Принимаются варианты на любых языках, лишь бы это были регулярные выражения.

Comment: `\b|\d|$` 16 подойдет?

Comment: `\b|\d| |$` -21

Comment: `r'\b|.|$'` - 21. @splash58, давайте ответ. С меня плюсик. Пока вы чемпион.

Comment: Паттерн в виде пустой строки - 11 совпадений.

Answer (score 1):

Пример `11` на JS:

```js
const str = '0123456789';
const regexp = /|/g;
const matches = str.match(regexp);

console.log('Length = ' + matches.length);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Лиха беда начало! А что матчит это `пусто|пусто`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Строку длиной 0, щас сделаю так, чтобы вывод результата, тоже показывался

Answer (score 1):

Если спецы не предложат варианта с несколькими проходами, то максимальная количество -- 10 символов + 11 границ между и вокруг них.

достигается в питоне

```
r'\b|.|$' - 21 совпадение
```

Comment: То есть, `2n + 1` - это потолок?

Comment: Из общих соображений, похоже.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Кстати в JS - это всё равно выдаёт 11. Так что думаю надо ещё и ЯП подбирать нужный :)

Comment: в смысле реализацию регексов? да, конечно. они сильно разные